# Set validation errors to angular 2 form model

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm making a small SPA with angular 2 and now I'm dealing with form validation.
By reading this tutorial : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html . I've completed making a simple form with simple validations. Here is my code :

Hero (model)

```
export class Hero{
   // Name of hero.
   email: string;

   // Password of hero.
   password: string;
}
```

insert-hero-card.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
import {Hero} from '../models/hero.model';


@Component({
    selector: 'insert-hero-card',
    templateUrl: 'app/components.template/insert-hero-card.html',
    outputs: ['insertHero']
})

export class InsertHeroCardComponent{

    // Information of hero stored here.
    hero: Hero;

    // This emitter is used for raising event when a hero is confirmed being inserted.
    insertHero : EventEmitter<Hero>;

    // Initialize component with settings.
    constructor(){
        this.hero = new Hero();
        this.hero.email = "A";
        this.hero.password = "ThisIsPassword";

        this.insertHero = new EventEmitter<Hero>();
    }

    // This event is fired when ok button is clicked.
    heroConfirmInsert(): void {
        //this.insertHero.emit(this.hero);
    }
}
```

insert-hero-card.html

```
<form class="panel panel-primary"
      #insertHeroCardControl="ngForm">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span>Hero</span>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <!-- Hero name -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <span class="control-label">Email</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input class="form-control"
                           [(ngModel)]="hero.email"
                           required
                           #heroEmail="ngModel"
                           name="heroEmail"/>

                    <div class="alert alert-info"
                         [hidden]="heroEmail.valid">Hero name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>

            <!-- Hero hp -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <span class="control-label">Hp</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <input class="form-control"
                           type="password"
                           [(ngModel)]="hero.password"
                           name="heroPassword"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                (click)="heroConfirmInsert()">Ok</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my code, I used **heroEmail.valid** to display/hide the name require validation. I wonder whether I can set the valid to true/false manually or not. Because in my back-end service, I can return a model like this :

```
{
  email: [
    "required",
    "maxlength",
    "minlenth"
  ]
}
```

If there is a way to set the response to model.errors, I can migrate the validation on service-side with client-side without rewriting the code.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

Comment: is there any specific time or event where you want to set it to true and false?

Comment: When the data is submitted to server. If there is any validation error available, HttpStatus 400 with the validation errors will return. The array will be map to model's errors.